# Cannot start a simple TCP/IP client

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to open a TCP/IP listener but when I run the code below, it crashes. It doesn't give me an error because when it crashes, it freezes and stops responding.

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 619);
TcpClient client;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server.Start();
    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

    if (client.Connected)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("connected");
    }
}
```

I know for a fact this port is free so that's not it. it crashes on this line:

```
client = server.acceptTcpClient();
```

Comment: A "crash" is something very specific: the process _terminates_, typically with some specific kind of error messages like an exception being thrown (but very rarely a process will just exit without warning). Do you really have a crash? If you don't and it's just that the `AcceptTcpClient()` method hasn't returned, then you have **no problem at all**. If you do, then please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem and explain what you've done so far to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing a blocking call on the UI thread which gives the appearance of a "Crashing" application.

You need to use another thread or do things asynchronously. Background worker might be a starting point.

```
private BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bgw.DoWork += Bgw_DoWork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgw.IsBusy)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        ((Button)sender).Content = "Cancel";
    }
    else
    {
        bgw.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Content = "Start";
}

private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 619);
    server.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            server.Stop();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (server.Pending())
            {
                var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                // handle client here or do something like below to return the client to the RunWorkerCompleted method in 
                // e.result
                e.Result = client;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are other options such as using server.AcceptTcpClientAsync() instead of polling the server.Pending() property. Also, polling in this way without using Thread.Sleep in between may be overkill, i.e., you're checking the property very frequently and wasting cycles.

Following all of that, you need to figure out a way to deal with the client in a way that makes sense for your application. One click per client accepted? Handle new connections forever as they arrive until you cancel the listener? Etc. Good luck

[BackgroundWorker tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

[AcceptTcpClientAsync MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: oh thanks, that makes more sense, do you know if i could connect it to the client program when they are both on the same computer? i have a virtual machine too on this computer which isnt working aswell

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. Your program hasn't crashed - the call to `AccpetTcpClient()` blocks waiting for an incoming connection:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to also open a TCP connection to port 619 from another thread, then your program will continue to run.

Comment: thankyou i have fixed it now, do you know if i would be able to run the client and server on the same laptop? i also have a virtual machine on here but that doesnt work either

Comment: Of course. You just make two .NET projects and run them independently.

Comment: hmm i did that and its not connecting, i cant tell if its the program or the network thats the problem

Comment: And welcome to StackOverlow.  The best way of saying thank-you is to upvote helpful answers, and accept the one which best solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> AcceptTcpClient is a blocking method

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When you call AcceptTcpClient, it will wait until a connection is made. Because it waits on the main thread (where also the GUI is running on), it will look like the program is frozen. Try using [AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or putting the accepting part in a different thread. That should solve your problem.

Desirius

Comment: thankyou i have fixed it now, do you know if i would be able to run the client and server on the same laptop? i also have a virtual machine on here but that doesnt work either